# Using wildcard in Custom event pattern for the event SSM parameter

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-ssm, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I am having a lambda function that trigger a Jenkins job. I want to invoke this lambda when a new ssm parameter is added. I have added the below Custom event pattern in the cloud-watch event pattern.

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ssm"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "Parameter Store Change",
    "Parameter Store Policy Action"
  ],
  "detail": {
      "name": [
          "/dev/*"
        ],
        "operation": [
          "Create",
          "Update",
          "Delete",
          "LabelParameterVersion"
  ]

}

}
```

This means, the lambda need to trigger if i create a ssm parameter start with "/dev/anystring" But the lambda is not triggering if i provide wild card. Any suggestion on this.?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this case you want to use the **prefix** comparison operator to filter based on values in the `detail.name` field.

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ssm"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "Parameter Store Change",
    "Parameter Store Policy Action"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "name": [ { "prefix": "/dev/" } ],
    "operation": [
      "Create",
      "Update",
      "Delete",
      "LabelParameterVersion"
    ]
  }
}
```

For more details, see [Reducing custom code by using advanced rules in Amazon EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/reducing-custom-code-by-using-advanced-rules-in-amazon-eventbridge/), especially example *2. All ATMs in New York City* in the section **Filtering events in a custom application**.

> I am contributing this on behalf of my employer, Amazon. My contribution is licensed under the MIT license. See [here](https://aws-preview.aka.amazon.com/tools/stackoverflow-samples-license/) for a more detailed explanation.